what is a good way to debug pytorch
We have an application where we call pytorch (and have been using torch.profiler to see what is going on), and we compare it to what happens when we call the same pytorch routines directly (in a unit test).
When we call pytorch from our application, we see many functions like aten::detach and aten::resolve_conj called that don't happen when we call pytorch directly.  We don't call these in our application.  My goal is to find out why these functions are called but only in our application.
The unit test looks roughly like this:
import pytest
import torch
import torch.profiler
import our_app

def test_add():
   a = torch.randn(2, 2, dtype=torch.float32).detach()
   with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU]) as prof1:
      b1 = torch.add(a, a)
   prof1.export_chrome_trace("torch_trace.json")
   
   with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU]) as prof2:
      b2 = our_app.add(a, a)
   prof2.export_chrome_trace("our_trace.json")
----------
our_app.py:

import torch

def add(lhs: torch.Tensor, rhs: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return torch.add(lhs, rhs)

I would expect the two trace.json files to be essentially the same, but the direct call is one line long with just "aten::add" where the one for our application has 22 operators in it.  I want to find out why.  I need to know what is going on in pytorch and what we have done to provoke it so.
At this point, I am considering building pytorch from source and debugging that. I am hoping there might be a better solution.
